# is there a way to build multiple parameters at once using choice paramerters in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I need to build a job using choice parameter in jenkins

This is my scenario

I am trying to build the job with this scenario

```
 Choice parameter:
   name: Build
   value:  value1
       value2
       value3
       value4
```

now i can build it by one by one values, But is that any way or command to build all the values at once?

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is basically a 4*1 matrix - 
Build with value1,
Build with value2,
Build with value3,
Build with value4

So, you can use a Multi-configuration project.
Define a Name for the value*(say X) and Provide value1, value2, value3, value4 as values in the configuration. Your Name for the value* (X) will be accessible as if they are environmental variables. That way Jenkins can pass all the value1, value2, value3, value4 for your build as input.

See https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project
It can be coupled with https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin for advance usecases!